# jQuery UI not detecting drop on first child of droppable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I have a `droppable` `div` that contains child elements that are not `droppable`.

For some reason, if you drop on the first child element, the `drop` event is not triggered, but it is on the second child element.

Here's a JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/bppn33q3/1/

Why is this? And how can I fix it?

EDIT: Wrong fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually *is* working. Look at what happens when you remove `margin-top: 50px`.

```
.drag {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/6bapjsjm/)

As you can see, the `margin` affects the placement calculations.

You could always play around with the [`tolerance` option](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-tolerance) - [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/eqtfxara/).

```
$('.drop').droppable({
    accept: '.drag',
    tolerance: "pointer",
    drop: function () {
        alert('dropped');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Playing with your fiddle, it appears that the issue is the css.

Check out my new fiddle after I removed your margin:

http://jsfiddle.net/bppn33q3/2/

```
.drag {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: aqua;
}
```